# Problem with undefined property( Cannot read property 'find' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with undefined "find".(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined )  I can't solve by my own, please see my code below.

```
class NetworkingEdit extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    data: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const paramsID = this.props.match.params.id;
    const { NetworkingData } = this.props;

    let currentEvent = NetworkingData.find(networking => {
      return networking.id == paramsID;
    });

    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      data: currentEvent
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.isLoading ? (
      <div>
        <p>Getting your data...</p>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <NetworkingMainForm
        {...this.props}
        data={this.state.data}
        id={this.props.match.params.id}
        addForm={false}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is in `NetworkingData` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass the `NetworkingData` prop from the parent component? If so, is it an array?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes, it is an array